# Variable Table Update Case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have (simplified for this example) TableA with Id, Speed and Description fields. TableB contains modifications to TableA. Table B contains a Id (FK so will match a Id in TableA), ModifiedSpeed and OriginalSpeed field.

Basically what I would like to be able to do is update either TableA Speed or TableB OriginalSpeed within one statement based on whether or not TableB has a record relating to TableA.

Here's what I have tried so far, hopefully it will give some idea of what I want as i'm not sure I am explaining it very well:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Description, a.Speed, CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT b.Id FROM TableB b WHERE b.Id = a.Id) THEN
        UPDATE TableB SET OriginalSpeed = 
            CASE
                WHEN (a.Speed is not null) THEN a.Speed
                WHEN a.Description = 'Motorway' THEN 70
                WHEN a.Description = 'A Road' THEN 60
                ELSE 30
            END
    ELSE
        UPDATE TableA SET Speed =
            CASE
                WHEN (a.Speed is not null) THEN a.Speed
                WHEN a.Description = 'Motorway' THEN 70
                WHEN a.Description = 'A Road' THEN 60
                ELSE 30
            END
END
FROM TableA a
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't have an update statement in the middle of a select statement and you can't use a case statement to switch the tables that you want to update.  Are you using Stored Procedures to update your data? Are you trying to create some kind of audit table?

Comment: @Barry: I am using a stored procedure for the update yes, I'm not very good with Sql though so am still trying to work out the limitations and best ways to do things. The TableA is road links but the requirement for the project is that the End User can modify the speed and that if it is modified the TableA value is not updated when the export stored procedure is run but the original value in the speed modifications table (TableB) is, if it has not been modified though, the TableA speed value should be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two statements, as others have said.

```
UPDATE
    b
SET
    OriginalSpeed = CASE
                WHEN (a.Speed is not null) THEN a.Speed
                WHEN a.Description = 'Motorway' THEN 70
                WHEN a.Description = 'A Road' THEN 60
                ELSE 30
            END
FROM
    TableB b
        inner join
    TableA a
        on
            b.Id = a.Id

UPDATE
    a
SET
    Speed = CASE
                WHEN (a.Speed is not null) THEN a.Speed
                WHEN a.Description = 'Motorway' THEN 70
                WHEN a.Description = 'A Road' THEN 60
                ELSE 30
            END
FROM
    TableA a
        left join
    TableB b
        on
           a.ID = b.ID
WHERE
    b.ID is null
```

The first query will only work when the join between tables A & B works (so there's a match between the rows in A & b). The second query, using the LEFT JOIN and where clause only updates rows in A for which we can't find a matching row in B.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update two tables with one statement.

Comment: +1. A stored procedure sounds best here, or at least some more complex code doing a select, then executing the richght insert. Note that you can submit that in one batch (i.e. one command execution), jsut not one sql statement (a command execution can execute multiple commands).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do something like this (I am guessing your datatypes):

```
Create Proc dbo.usp_ProcedureName

@Id int,
@Speed int

As Begin


If Exists (Select ID From TableB Where Id = @Id)
    Begin

        Update TableB
        Set OriginalSpeed = @Speed
        Where Id = @Id


    End
Else
    Begin

        Update TableA
        Set Speed = @Speed
        Where Id = @Id

    End



End
Go
```

You should be passing the ID and new speed as parameters to the Stored Procedure.  The SP should then simply update these values. i.e. The logic for deciding the speed etc should be done before passing the values to the Stored Procedure.

If the Id exists in TableB then it will update TableB otherwise it will update TableA

Comment: I can't work out how I should call this with the logic for speed, basically I want to run this for every item in TableA with the Speed based off the Description, was wondering if you could help me work out where to start? Thanks

Comment: @manatherin - ah sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were doing the update on a per ID basis. Rather than me editing my answer and duplicating - You should use the answer that Damien has provided. This is the solution to your problem.